# Access subelement of document by natural index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following schema:

```
{
    "_id" : "1128",
    "revisions" : {
        "1" : {
            "message": "Hi I am revision1!!",
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1462477684),
            "userId" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "2" : {
            "message": "Hi I am revision2!!",
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1462477777),
            "userId" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        .... // Goes up to 90 for example
    }
}
```

I just need to return the "message" for revisions[2], what would the syntax be?

I've tried:

```
db.test.findOne({"_id":"1128"}, {"revisions": {$slice:[2,1]}});
```

And

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id:"1128"}},
    {$unwind: '$revisions'},
    {$match: {'$revisions.$':39}}
]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: revisions are arrays or subdocument (maybe need to add [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method and the wrong operator for the job.

Simply use the [`findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) method and access the "2" field with [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

```
db.test.findOne( { "_id": "1128" }, { "revisions.2": 1 } )
```

which produces:

```
{
    "_id" : "1128",
    "revisions" : {
        "2" : {
            "message" : "Hi I am revision2!!",
            "timestamp" : NumberLong(1462477777),
            "userId" : NumberLong(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx I'll give this is a go. In my defense I was trying `findOne` but to no avail. I didn't know about the dot notation for accessing indices.

Answer (score 0):

I'v tested these

for revisions with id 1

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"_id":"1128"},{"revisions.1":""})
```

for revisions with id 2

```
db.getCollection('test').find({"_id":"1128"},{"revisions.2":""})
```